# Compatibility of SQL Server 2005 / 2008 and Windows XP UK Edition

Tags: sql-server, windows-xp, sql-server-express

Today I was told that the version of Windows XP for the UK is not the same as the one used in the US.

1. Is this true? And if so, is there
   somewhere where I can learn the
   differences?
2. Are SQL Server 2005 / 2008 Express
   Editions compatible with Windows XP
   UK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run English UK Windows XP and SQL Server Express OK. With both UK and Swiss German keyboards too

When you install SQL Server the default language is "us_english". This setting is independent of OS locale. There can be issues with dates, but this why we have ISO data formats.

Do you mean ["Windows XP Edition N"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_editions#Windows_XP_Edition_N) which vanished almost without trace...?

Comment: I see. That's good to hear. Not sure about version N, the person simply referred to it as "XP in the UK."

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the default keyboard layout and default regions and the way the computer does dates (11/24/2010 vs 24/11/2010) but I may be wrong.

I think it was only when 7 came out and the whole antitrust thing that they actually made any major changes. Which was allowing UK users to choose their default browser during installation.

As far as I know there should be no compatibility issues with the express versions of MS SQL 2005/2008.

I looked online a little as well and did not see any info stating otherwise.

Express is free just install it and see what happens worse comes to worse it wont install...